# Kendo UI - column chart from JSON array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

In my AngularJS application I am using Kendo UI to create charts. I have a JSON Array as below.

```
        [
          {
          "date": "2016-06-24",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-23",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-22",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-21",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-20",
          "competitor": [
            {
                "price": 1223,
                "competitorName": "competitorA"
             },
                      {
                "price": 1222,
                "competitorName": "competitorB"
             }
          ]
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-19",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-18",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-17",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-16",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-15",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-14",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-13",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-12",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-11",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-10",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-09",
          "competitor":       [
                      {
                "price": 1345,
                "competitorName": "competitorA"
             },
                      {
                "price": 1604,
                "competitorName": "competitorC"
             }
          ]
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-08",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-07",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-06",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-05",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-04",
          "competitor": [
            {
                "price": 1343,
                "competitorName": "competitorB"
             },
                      {
                "price": 1604,
                "competitorName": "competitorC"
             }
          ]
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-03",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-02",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-06-01",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-05-31",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-05-30",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-05-29",
          "competitor": [
               {
                "price": 1370,
                "competitorName": "competitorD"
             }
          ]
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-05-28",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-05-27",
          "competitor": []
       },
          {
          "date": "2016-05-26",
          "competitor": []
       }
    ]
```

I want to create a column chart for these data. The chart should be categorized by date. The thing is, competitors are varying for date by date. As an example, for the date **2016-06-20**, competitors are **competitorA & competitorB**. Also some dates don't have competitors. Some has two or one. That means, in the column chart, column series count is varying date by date.

**UPDATED**

I just want to set colors for the series of the chart as below.

CompetitorC - Green (every time CompetitorC should be green)
Every Other competitors - blue with different shades

And I want to set chart theme to "back". I tried following.

```
var transData = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){        
var date =  data[i].date;
if (data[i].competitor.length > 0){
  for (var j=0; j<data[i].competitor.length; j++){
    var obj = {}
    obj.date = date;
    obj.competitorName = data[i].competitor[j].competitorName;
    obj.price =  data[i].competitor[j].price;
    if(obj.competitorName==='CompetitorC') {
        obj.color = 'green';
    }
    transData.push(obj);            
  }          
} else {
  var obj = {}
  obj.date = date;
  obj.competitorName = "";
  obj.price = "";
  transData.push(obj);
}        
}
```

Then in the chart:

```
series: [{
              field: 'price',
              categoryField: "date",
              name: "#= group.value #",
              colorField: 'color'
          }]
```

Then my chart set color **green** to **competitorC** but legend is not changing to green. How do I fix it & how can I set blue with different shades to other competitors?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would transform you JSON so and then use grouping on competitorName.  You end up with a simpler array:

```
[
  { date: "", competitorName: "", "price: ""},
  ...
]
```

Dates will be repeated where more than one competitor exists at that date.

```
  var transData = [];
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){        
    var date =  data[i].date;
    if (data[i].competitor.length > 0){
      for (var j=0; j<data[i].competitor.length; j++){
        var obj = {}
        obj.date = date;
        obj.competitorName = data[i].competitor[j].competitorName;
        obj.price =  data[i].competitor[j].price;
        transData.push(obj);            
      }          
    } else {
      var obj = {}
      obj.date = date;
      obj.competitorName = "";
      obj.price = "";
      transData.push(obj);
    }        
  }
```

With the date transformed, you use the grouping functionality of the kendo datasource:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
 theme: "material",
 dataSource: {
      data: transData,
      group:{field: 'competitorName'}, 
      sort: {field: "date", dir: "asc"},
      schema: {
          model: {
              fields: {
                  date: {
                      type: "date"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  legend: { visible: true, position: "bottom" },
  seriesDefaults: {type: 'column',},
  series: [{
      field: 'price',
      categoryField: "date",
      name: "#= group.value #"
  }],
  tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    template: "#= series.name #<br />#= kendo.toString(category, 'yyyy-MM-dd') # = #= value #"
  },
});
```

Here is a dojo demo:

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/iqAhi)**

Comment: Working as I really expected.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Colud u plz check on my edited question under **UPDATED** heading ?

Comment: @Rose18, you are setting colors of individual points not the series, so the legend does not know. Try this:  http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OnEMO